# See the branches of a repository in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, branch, bamboo

I want to see all the branches present in my version control in Jenkins dashboard. If any branch is pushed, it should be replicated in Jenkins too. How do I get it?
Do I need to use any plugin? This is possible in Bamboo. I am trying to manage my version control through Jenkins.

Comment: which VCS you are using ? and you want to build a particular branch with jenkins ..please elaborate your question.

Comment: With git, use multibranch pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Branches in repository can reflect in jenkins but you need to be specific at what level you are trying to run.
either you want a job with new branch name or you simply just a drop down menu to list the branches.

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.exec(
 outputproperty:"text",
         errorproperty: "error",
         resultproperty: "exitValue",
 failonerror: false,
 executable: 'svn') 
{
arg(line:"""list      https://REPOSITORY/branches/""")
}
def result = new Expando(
     text: ant.project.properties.text,
     error: ant.project.properties.error,
     exitValue: ant.project.properties.exitValue as Integer,
     toString: {text}
 )
 if (result.exitValue != 0){
     throw new Exception("""command failed with ${result.exitValue}
executed: ${commandLiteral}
error: ${result.error}
text: ${result.text}""")
 }
print result
```

run the above code in **localhost:8080/script or jenkinsurl/script**
This will display the list of branches.
You can run this snippet of code in any groovy accepted script console.
Note that jenkins inbuilt have the capabilty to run groovy scripts.